# Debug classes like org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Just wanted to know if there is any option of debugging deep into the core framework classes like  org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor,org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet etc..

Because while debugging in eclipse i am only able to see the line numbers in these classes increase(Since these classes only display as .class files and "Source Not Found" error is coming) and only after stepping into the class i have written am able to debug and see the data in each step.

Is there anyway to prevent the "Source Not Found" error and debug into the class files also...

Kindly ignore if this is a dumb question...just wanted to check whether i can go deep into these core classes and debug.

Comment: Are you using Maven? It makes is easy to download the source code of the binaries that you are using as dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the sources from the apache repository and select the "Attach source" button into Eclipse, then you'll see the code as if it was built in your workspace and debug through it